# Changes made to object in child component, visible in parent component?

Tags: angular, typescript

Pass an object to the child component.
<child [model]="parentModel">

Make change to a certain property in the object in the child component.
Will this change now be visible in the parent component?

As per my knowledge, change will not be reflected, if we are passing numbers, strings, boolean
but if pass objects, change should be visible in the parent component (As we are passing it like a reference)

Comment: Yes, that is where @Output decorators are used. Another way is to use behaviorSubject in a service to reflect the changes.

Comment: @Jai, there are no output decorators involved here. model in child component will have input decorator

Comment: Yes you are correct. You have implementation for `@Input` which responds on inflow of data only. For outflow you have to use `@Output` decorator to emit the updated value

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, you can pass an object to a child component as a property. If you want changes made to the object in the child component to be reflected in the parent component, you need to ensure that the object is mutable.

When you pass an object as an input to a child component in Angular, the reference to the object is passed, not a copy of the object. So, any changes made to the object in the child component will be reflected in the parent component, because they are modifying the same object.

Answer (score 0):

When you pass a reference type value from `parent` to `child` it means either of your components would work with the same value. So it will work with all changes of your reference value. Reference type can be not only an `object`, but also an `array` structure.

Another question is how your `parent` component knows when to redraw a view to show changes in the value. That problem can be solved by change detection system in `Angular`.

If your changes trigger event in the `parent` component then you no need to worry about - change detection will do everything itself. If not, then you have to know when to trigger `detectChanges` method of `ChangeDetectorRef` service in `parent` component. For example, it can be done with `@Output` decorator in child component, or you can even inject `ChangeDetectorRef` with option `SkipSelf` to the `child` and trigger `detectChanges` method there, when object changes... there are lot of possibilities to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As long as same reference and mutable, You will get the updated value in parant component.

Playground: [Parent-Child-Obj-Ref](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ikjp3m?file=src%2Fmain.ts)